# Where can I find interesting programming discussions?

Tags: discussion, subjective

I have noticed a lot of discussion type 'questions' that are asked on SO that get closed have some really interesting replies. I understand why these types of questions get closed and completely agree with the reasoning behind doing so. Being someone that is interested by the discussion that is generated by these closed questions, where could I find websites that are targeted towards this?

I imagine that the best sites will be forums with an active and positive community but I find it hard to gauge  how interesting a forum is without actively participating in it for some time and with the sheer volume of programming related forums out there, it could be a while before I come across one that is worthwhile.

Do any of you know of any such sites/forums that may interest me and/or other members of SO who enjoy this type of discussion?

I will update this question with a list of any good sites that are recommended to me or that I discover.

#### See also:

[Good programming website like Stack Overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387797/good-programming-website-like-so/) particularly [CrazyJugglerDrummer's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387797/good-programming-website-like-so/907126#907126)

For **RSS Feeds**:
[What are the best RSS feeds for programmers/developers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34644/what-are-the-best-rss-feeds-for-programmers-developers)

Comment: what definition of 'meta' does this fall under?

Comment: @Jimmy: it'd make a decent faq question (if merged with some / all of the existing versions of the same question) - much nicer to say, "try posting there" than "don't post here"! In the style of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions but for non-questions rather than non-programming questions.

Comment: this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387797/good-programming-website-like-so/907126#907126

Comment: don't worry, you are in the correct place

Comment: Check out... http:www.advcodes.com   for All programming solutions

Comment: The link "Good programming website like Stack Overflow?" and some of the other links in the comments is broken. I think this is a very good question, because there are a few types of questions which are good but not a fit for SO, apparently, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work?rq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a **Question and Answer** site.

That's a little different than a discussion forum.

With a Question, you really want an answer. A concrete *the answer to this will help me finish project X* type question.

Your question essentially asked programmers to navel-gaze. At best, any answer you got would be opinion, and at worst it would devolve into a flame-fest.

We have Reddit and Slashdot for those.

Comment: Your most recent addition is somewhat inaccurate. Programmers Stack Exchange discourages trivial questions like *What should I decorate my cubicle with?* and attempts to promote more stimulating topics like [What is the good/bad decision you made in your mid 20's about your career?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/18120/what-is-the-good-bad-decision-you-made-in-your-mid-20s-about-your-career)

Comment: @Nathan Taylor I was being facetious. Whoosh.

Comment: Discussion aversion is wrong. If you very much want an exciting answer, than a discussion is oftentimes the way to get there.

Comment: @mario I don't want an exciting answer, I want an answer that solves my problem. :-)

Comment: Damn pragmatism. I hope there is a special hell for pragmatists! ;]

Comment: @Nathan Taylor Ironically, the question you mentioned has been deleted...

Answer (score 10):

For Perl, it's hard to beat [The Perl Monastery](http://www.perlmonks.org), which has been around since 2000, and has a lot of heavy hitters posting regularly.

Comment: I'll second that... If only every language had something similar the world would be a much better place.

Comment: If every other language had that, I don't think we'd have Stackoverflow :)

Comment: For C++, isn't it comp.lang.c++.moderated ?

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly a programming discussion medium per se, but for all sorts of programming and technical discussions, I always head to the IRC chat server [irc.freenode.net](http://freenode.net/).

Comment: The successor is [Libera Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libera_Chat) (*irc.libera.chat*).

Answer (score 5):

I think [LesssThanDot](http://lessthandot.com) is great.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at lessthandot.com."*

Comment: Also [noted by  
Darek Nędza](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions#comment1130172_85216).

Comment: Info for a future edit: `http://www.lessthandot.com/` (HTTP, with "`www`") works (*"archive of the posts published to LessThanDot from 2008 to 2018"*). `https://lessthandot.com/` (HTTPS, without "www") gives *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at lessthandot.com"*.

Comment: cont' - "`https://www.lessthandot.com/` and `http://lessthandot.com/` both result in (*"Potential Security Risk Ahead"* - yes, one is for HTTP (without "`www`") and one is for HTTPS (***with*** "www")). The latter is the one in the Markdown source, but depending on exactly it is opened from the rendered page, it may result in the HTTPS version actually being opened instead (with result *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at lessthandot.com"*).

Comment: As for the purpose here, LessThanDot is now dead (stopped in 2018).

Answer (score 5):

For good quality answers (not just guesses, wrong answers from noobs or useless links) and a free open environment to qet qualitative answers (e.g. open discussions) as well as quantative then http://lessthandot.com/ is a good place to go.  Several Microsoft SQL MVP's are resident their aswell as ASP, C# and .NET experts, and there are brainstorming fora to help with getting to a more robust answer than a snippet of code and investigate ideas.. e.g. there are architecture and design fora, which require a lot more than code snippets.  Strong and completed answers can be posted to the wiki for easy access as the answer to a problem (you can see the SQL Hacks and C# Hacks on there).  You'll also find IT Professionals and Students discussion areas aswell as a 'let your hair down' area for a bit of fun.  It's also a generic forum - so it can be your one-stop-shop for different aspect of an IT pro's life.

You definitely do not want to go to tek-tips - it is a nightmare community which shuns a lot of people, and blanket bans country IP ranges, aswell as having very poor answers - all the top MVP's left ages ago.

Sometimes you may want to go to a specific forum - e.g. the perl java fora mentioned in the above (or wherever they end up) posts, as these can have the highest concentration of experts in that subject.

IRC for me is noisy and mixed in quality of response - it can be a good last resort though if no-one else can answer the question.

Comment: lessthandot is no longer active. The last version was from April: https://web.archive.org/web/20190422234958/http://lessthandot.com/

Answer (score 4):

The [programming forums at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Forums/List.aspx) have been a great help to me in the past.

Comment: Check out... http://www.advcodes.com   for All programming solutions

Comment: It is [still active in 2022](https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/5857917/Re-Please-help-with-dynamic-objects-modeling-Blazo).

Comment: Though that particular corner seems to have become a ghost town (practically no activity since early 2022). But *[C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Forums/1649/Csharp)* and *[Artificial Intelligence](https://www.codeproject.com/Forums/1969389/Artificial-Intelligence)* is active (2023-01). If you want the full forum experience, that seems to be the place to go to...

Answer (score 4):

[Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com)

Answer (score 3):

Joelonsoftware.com used to be pretty good. Not so much anymore.

Comment: The blog or the forum? Wasn't the forum shut down?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I was almost certainly referring to the forum, but it's hard to remember what I was thinking over 12 years ago.  I can't remember when the forum shut down but that might be the origin of "not so much anymore".

Answer (score 2):

Sitepoint's [PHP Application Design](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=147) forum isn't terrible, it at least gives you a level of discussion above the basics of PHP that other communities seem to be mired in.

Comment: It is [still active in 2022](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-create-a-free-cdn-content-delivery-network-account/380972).

Answer (score 2):

The usenet newsgroup comp.lang.tcl has an extremely high signal to noise ratio. The people there are friendly and exceptionally helpful. All of the people who regularly contribute to the Tcl language participate. Best of all, there are no fanboys there -- everyone is very professional.

Alas, that last point is likely one of the reasons Tcl continues to lose mindshare, since we are happy to promote other languages from time to time in the spirit of using the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to actually go out in the real world and meet actual real people then ALT.NET Open Spaces events provoke some very interesting discussions.

I was at the UK ALT.NET Open Space Conference last weekend and the discussions ranged across many topics and it didn't stay confined to things born of Microsoft technologies (although there was a natural bias to stuff that runs on .NET)

One of the guys who were involved in organising it is launching a thing called the Alternative Network (ALTNET without the dot) which is a similar idea but cross more technologies.

Comment: But be sure and wear sunscreen and a good hat. The real world is full of harmful radiation...

Comment: Isn't [ALT .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/march/%7b-end-bracket-%7d-what-is-alt-net) long gone?

Comment: Quite probably, my answer was written over 12 years ago. :)

Answer (score 2):

I used to post a lot on the [C# newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/topics) - these days my time goes into SO instead, but the benefit of the newsgroup was that there really were good discussions.

It really depends on exactly what you're after: "general programming" or specific topics, but newsgroups may well be worth looking into.

Other than that, blogs, podcasts and user groups.

Answer (score 2):

For discussion, nothing beats Usenet. Even on its 30th birthday, nothing has been invented that comes even close. (Just one example: on the Usenet, I can use my own client to compose articles [without some stupid JavaScript screwing up my keybindings](http://Meta.StackOverflow.Com/questions/13065/).)

Answer (score 1):

[Javaranch](http://www.javaranch.com/) for Java beginners

Comment: It is [still active in 2022](https://coderanch.com/t/749012/java/java-program-check-print-happy).

Answer (score 1):

Some other ones:

CSScreator - 
http://csscreator.com/forum

Some good (albeit a bit critical for beginners) veterans in css there

W3Schools - 
http://w3schools.invisionzone.com

Good in the diversity of different things they have on there.

Other than that, irc channels are great when available. 
irc.freenode.net is a programmers haven, some popular channels:
php
jquery
vb.net
(Don't forget the pound)

Depending the time of day, great. Remember to use pastebin/pastie in order for people to help you properly if you have sample code on irc channels though.

Comment: Both are [still active](https://csscreator.com/topic/resizing-iframe) [in 2022](https://w3schools.invisionzone.com/topic/63227-identical-css-and-js-files/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Programming Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/)?

Comment: Thanks, I already use it and find that the 'Ask Progit' (http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/search?q=progit) questions often generate interesting discussion.

Comment: This used to be good, but it hasn't been for a year at least.

Comment: But they don't have discussions(?) - *"Do you have a question? Check out /r/learnprogramming, /r/cscareerquestions, or Stack Overflow."*

Answer (score 0):

I like the [programming talk](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=39) board on the ubuntu forums a lot, but you won't find much support when it comes to IIS or win32 api issues. But there are a lot of competent people there (don't get me wrong, there are also here :D) and there is a large variety of subjects.

Comment: It is [still active in 2022](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2471487&s=299302bfb58b5534726c981fa39d73d9).

Answer (score 0):

The [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/) [Open Forum](http://episteme.arstechnica.com/) has many experts from Microsoft, Apple, Cisco, and such. There is some incredible insider info posted occasionally. They can be rather nasty to newbies, though.

Comment: *Open Forum* (`http://episteme.arstechnica.com/`) redirects to `https://arstechnica.com/`. Has it been shut down?

Comment: Yup, looks like it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

[CompSci.ca](http://compsci.ca/v3/index.php) has some boards on various programming and university questions that I tend to post on every now and then.

[AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/) and [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/us/) have forums that if one wants to go outside of the SO group of sites that I've found useful at times.

Comment: All three have some activity in 2022. [Sample CompSci.ca forum post](http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?p=292243&no=1#292243). [Sample AnandTech forum post](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/asus-k8n-e-deluxe-helping-building-recomendation.1406663/#post-40690957). [Sample Tom's Hardware forum post](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/are-these-pc-parts-good-together.3743467/#post-22598779).

Answer (score 0):

[DZone](http://dzone.com) is another great resource which acts as a central point for a large range of development sites/blogs/articles.

Answer (score 0):

msdn blogs and forums are good
autohotkey forum: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum

Comment: That link: *"[These forums are obsolete and new topics can no longer be created](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum)"*. However, there is a successor, `https://www.autohotkey.com/boards`. [Sample from 2022](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=442436&sid=87f02eaaf73709cd1cf0452d8094712f#p442436).

Answer (score 0):

The C2.com wiki is a hugely interesting and odd site http://c2.com/cgi/wiki

Comment: AKA [WikiWikiWeb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WikiWikiWeb). *"On February 1, 2015 Cunningham announced that the Wiki had been rewritten as a single-page application and migrated to the new Federated Wiki."*. The new place ***seems*** to be a ghost town, though.