# Proposed badge: Philosopher

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

> "Asked a question that received 50 answers."

You could have a few of these:

Socrates: bronze, 50 answers

Plato: silver, 100 answers

Aristotle: gold, 150 answers

Or, if you're not into the whole ranking-Greek-philosophers thing, you could just have: Inquirer (50) and Philosopher (150)..

Well I'll admit these names aren't so great, except "Philosopher" which I love, so I welcome suggestions. But the concept is solid - questions that many people feel the need to answer are remarkable and as such badge-worthy IMO.

---

Some examples of questions that have > 150 answers (most of them have much much more):

1. [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)
2. [Great programming quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes)
3. [What do you use to keep notes as a developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756/what-do-you-use-to-keep-notes-as-a-developer)
4. [What are Code Smells? What is the best way to correct them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114342/what-are-code-smells-what-is-the-best-way-to-correct-them)
5. [What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon)
6. [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)

Comment: btw, I didn't want to post this in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas because I figured it's such an old question nobody would notice another answer, so I hope that's cool

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/badges-positive-only/

Comment: Not a fan... frankly I don't like badges that reward "poll" or "what's your favorite programmer ______" type threads.

Comment: @Mehrdad, yea, that's what inspired this badge proposal. Why would "philosopher" be a negative badge? These questions are mostly extremely popular. Besides, wouldn't you enjoy being the one of the five to close these overly popular questions? :P

Comment: Those aren't particularly great questions. More like legacy ones.

Comment: @Assaf: I believe most questions with lots of answers are the worst questions on StackOverflow; based on the definition of SO in its FAQ.

Comment: @Mehrdad, well maybe someone can do a query and list them by order. All I managed to gather for the list above was from the "most votes" page...
@random, what's wrong with highlighting legacy questions?

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like you want to encourage endless discussion on a question & answer site. You should totally drop that <s>and use jQuery</s> thought and think about writing better, well defined questions that will lead toward a solid answer.

The concept is not solid is just cracks it wide for open-ended questions with a meandering list of answers.

If a question is remarkable enough, then there will be plenty of views on it. In which case, there are already badges such rubber-necking: [Famous](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question), [Notable](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/27/notable-question) and [Popular Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question).

Comment: Having 200 answers to a question is hardly a discussion. Having 200 comment threads - that's a discussion. I'll grant 200 answers means the question can be controversial or entertaining.. but how is that negative? And please, I appreciate your input about this proposal, but I have a right to disagree with you on the matter of what should be encouraged/discouraged on SO. And I don't really appreciate being told to "think about writing better questions" because I think I've contributed my share of good questions to SO.

Comment: SO is this, have a problem, post a question. Get an answer or two that solves your problem. If you wind up with 200 answers, that's not a good question. That's a topic of dicussion.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know that questions with huge numbers of answers are something that SO should encourage... Often as not, > 10-15 answers means *there is no answer* (or everyone has their own opinion as to what that answer is... or no one cares to read the existing answers, so there are scores of duplicates...)

Remember, SO *isn't* a discussion site. If you have some deep philosophical question you'd like to discuss with your fellow developers, you're better off starting here: [**Where can I find interesting programming discussions?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions)

Comment: That's true of questions that 10-15 answers. But not 50, 100 or 150. Those are likely classics. Maybe some of them tend to be contentious or entertaining, but that's not necessarily a bad thing. See, once a question does have, say, 20 answers, people wouldn't really keep answering unless they feel overwhelmed by the need to chip in their own 2c. That kind of question _is_ badge-worthy. I'll try to find examples to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A50 and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A100 and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A150

Comment: Note that these already tend to collect Popular / Notable / Famous Question badges.

Comment: I agree that they do correlate with other badges. But that's true of several other badges as well (remarkable questions tend to be remarkable in more than one way). Buyt let's not restart that old argument now about the true nature of SO. Sure, it's not a discussion site, but it does seem to have some amazing discussion questions that sometimes do slip through, and this can highlight some of them.

Comment: Well, usually they aren't discussions. They're GTKY questions, or polls, or popularity contests. Which don't really fit with the whole "philosopher" thing at all... But then, neither does SO's extremely limited threading, where any *debate* quickly degenerates into brief, confused comments.

Answer (score 4):

Is this really a behavior we want to *encourage* on the site?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/badges-positive-only/

Comment: jeez. I'm never posting a badge proposal again. duh, I came up with the question after your recent post, because I do think it's a positive badge. But I guess I'm fighting windmills here... nm, shut it down.