# Why is my community wiki topic closed?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

I'm relatively new to SO, and I learned quickly that subjective topics like "what is your favorite language" are subjective and argumentative and should go in the community wiki. I wanted to get input on what people thought were some cool or [useful Java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327451/most-interesting-useful-java-classes-closed), but the topic was closed on the grounds that it was argumentative and subjective. Doesn't this go against the whole idea of the community wiki(people asking fun or educational questions with no definite answer)?

If you feel wronged like I do, vote to reopen the question. If not, please explain why my question would be closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main point of the community wiki is not to ask fun questions. It's only the best way to ask questions indeed without definitive answer, especially ones involving a list of answers that can be edited by other people. It's for situation when ownership of an answer shouldn't matter.

However, this has nothing to do with the reasons your question was closed, in my opinion. It was closed because it's mostly a discussion, and you are strongly asking about people "preference, opinion".

Community wiki is not a shield against that.

Also, and probably the biggest reason in my opinion, your question is more or less similar to [Hidden Features of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java) and [Most useful free third party Java libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-third-party-java-libraries), most answers to your question can go to these other ones.

Comment: In general, it can seem unfair to be closed like this, when you see that other questions survived, but they survived mostly because they were asked at the very beginning. These ones are now tolerated, but not the new ones. This is probably why people voted to close your question.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, but my question is distinctly different from older questions. I do see how it would be dismissed on the grounds of being a discussion. That said, what's a good place to take these "discussions"? I think forums might work but I like how much feedback you can get on SO and the sheer amount of knowledge.

Comment: @Rafe - this question could have some pointers for you: [Where can I find interesting programming discussions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions)