# Statistical query: from 'most popular' to 'deleted' in a new york minute

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I've been noticing a rather depressing trend. If I go to the 10k tools, and look at the questions with the most upvotes, many of them immediately strike me as needing a close vote.

And I'm clearly not alone: frequently by the time I see them they are, in fact closed.

From my perspective as a undisguised proponent of relatively tight control on the content of SO, this is just another diagnosis of the broadening gap between the subjective-upvote-muppets and the janitors.

Others may find other interpretations.

In any case, I wonder: is this really as frequent as it looks? So I invite the data miners to take a stab at finding out. How often does a question shoot up 10 votes and then get closed, let alone reopened, in short order.

Comment: See [Community Wiki questions and the subjective close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61906/community-wiki-questions-and-the-subjective-close) for discussion.

Comment: I'm testing some query's, and it doesn't look like you can see multiple closes and reopens, only the last closed date

Comment: It's not possible to look at historical close data (unfortunately). See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37524/request-for-data-dump-to-include-more-closed-question-info

Answer (score 1):

My personal, unscientific (and I know what I'm talking about, I'm a scientist...) sense is that is is *not* ubiquitous, but is more common than is comfortable.

I fear that is foretells a slow slide into irrelevance for Stack Overflow, but don't think that it will happen fast: there is too much good in the community to die quickly.

Comment: Jeff made it very clear that he was much more disturbed by overactive 'delete' than by what I'll derisively call 'the muppet show.' Perhaps some actual data will either show that he's right or attract his attention.