# Flagging or Closing CW Questions

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, old-questions, not-constructive

I've been going through some older questions, specifically looking for shopping questions that should be flagged as "not constructive".

While going through the questions, I found https://stackoverflow.com/q/2539390/250725.

I went to flag it since it is a prototypical "not constructive" question, and if it was asked now, it would have been closed and downvoted into oblivion.  But I hesitated because it is marked as a CW question.  There is even a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539390/what-web-based-programming-environments-exist-on-which-to-learn#comment2539640_2539390) suggesting that the OP make it a CW questions since it was subjective.

Is there any special treatment that CW questions receive that should permit this question to remain open, or is this an old definition for CW?  I did find [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61906/182513) potentially related question, but it is dated at roughly the same time as the CW question in question, so I'm not sure how valid it is anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. a Community Wiki is meant for a post to be edited more easily (because even very low reputation users may edit it freely). It doesn't make it close-proof or flag-proof.

If the question is still lousy in Stack Overflow standards, either edit it, or close it. It being a CW doesn't change the fact it's not a good question.