# Is there a way to distinguish real good questions from tons of crap?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The title says it all.

Voting system is not an option as it works **against** interesting questions, just because most of folks have no idea of the matter.
Say, there is a question like this one: [How can I avoid getting a 502 Gateway Error while restarting php-fpm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164409/php-how-to-avoid-502-gateway-error-upon-restarting-php-fpm)
It will scarcely get +1 or +2, while yet another "Headers already sent" will get 10+ as it's familiar for the masses.
So, I suppose it will get less relevance with search.

I think there is no way, But it's really important thing, I think. Number of questions being increased and every day it become harder to find a diamond among the rust.
Every other collaboration society ends up with creating some sort of FAQ system to reduce number of repetitive questions, but such practice seems against SO ideology and profits.

May be it would be possible to make some Superupvote button, making +10 at once? Costs you -5 to prevent frequent use and available for the 10k+ guys only?

Or, going even further in dreams, if it possible to make some "goodness mark", to mark good questions with good answers ("headers already sent" kind can be marked too of course), directly adding to relevance?
Such an improvement will help to solve stackoverflow dualism - it pretends to be a source of knowledge but in real it turns out to be heap of garbage + online chat.
It's ok with chat but I wish there was some distinction between programmers questions and repetitive chat logs in the search results.

Or well, it can be put this way:
I'd be interesting not only in answering questions but also in reading interesting ones too. But there are literally thousands of repetitive noobish questions and it's just impossible to pick pro ones off the stream.
If there was some mark, or separate feed, something named like `pro.stackoverflow.com,` it would be great to read like news feed. With 10k limit to press the button of course.

**Long story short: I wish Stackoverflow was not only kind of automatic answering machine, but also indeed source of some knowledge.**

Comment: I wonder how many PHP developers besides OP find that question superremarkable? It appears to me, it's highly individual.

Comment: Seems like the title didn't say it all.

Comment: I love the supervote/rep-loss idea. There's way too many difficult questions/answers that go unrecognized.

Comment: I just can't help but shake the feeling this is another one of those "I hate n00bs" questions. And I use the term "question" loosely. Executive summary: they're not going anywhere, we don't need super awesome double-plus vote features to make "us" feel 1337, and the tone that discussions like this quickly take on is antithetical to the site's principles at large.

Comment: @cody oh yeah, them site principles. Kindness, nursery, charity and number of ads shown.

Comment: This question is hilarious as it's been asked many times on meta.  Irony ftw.

Comment: @Cody, to put it straight, answer as much noob questions as I did first, and then accuse me for hating noobs. I don't hate noobs. I wish this site had something else beside noob questions. Is it a crime?

Comment: @Col: I answer noob questions all the time, and I didn't mean to suggest that you don't (I don't follow your activity closely enough to make such a statement). I think the site has both; I find plenty of intellectually stimulating questions and answers in the tags I browse. Granted, I'm a C#/.NET/C++/WinAPI guy, so maybe there's more activity in my neck of the woods, but I think it's hardly fair to imply SO has gone *completely* down the tubes in terms of content. As the site has become more well-known, you get more beginner questions. You also get some advanced questions. Seems to balance out

Answer (score 10):

> Every other collaboration society ends
>   up with creating some sort of FAQ
>   system to reduce number of repetitive
>   questions, but such practice seems
>   against SO ideology and profits.

Really?

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/faq

Link to dupes and the faq will improve, it shows the most linked questions. You can also include some common knowledge and questions in the wiki.

Comment: LOL, you didn't get the point :) Does it reduce number of repetitions? Of course, not. It's useless faq, nobody bother to search them. Why, if its lot easier just to ask and it's even encouraged to ask, not to use search and faqs? Face the truth, one FAQ lookup makes only one ad to show, but one question makes 20-30. Feel the difference :) So, another mechanism is needed.

Comment: Such a shame, I haven't read through 8,845 faq questions before asking my own :)

Answer (score 2):

*(Maybe if you asked a [question with positive vibes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13198/156011), you will actually get somewhere)*

- Is there a need to flag the useless web sites in the internets<sup>TM</sup>?
- Is there a need to remove the useless blogs from blogspot?

Why do you care? Unless you went searching for them, you wouldn't even know they existed.  Even if you tried to find them, [your preferred search engine] may show you other more interesting sites instead.

There will always be niche users who like to visit [subjectively rated] interesting web sites.  Your average Joe Bloggs follows stumbleupon/twitter/digg/reddit/[your site here] and would frown on hitting some niche site for "tooth extraction stories".

This is the same philosophy that SO seems to take.  Let the questions come and the search engine will deal with giving users what is most relevant to them.  The crowd using SO has spoken - the majority want to see things

1. they can understand enough to learn from/relate to
2. common enough that they may/will come across/find a use for

Your taste is not representative of the internets [SO users].  If you have to satisfy your interests, I would suggest visiting data.stackexchange.com or using the API with custom queries, but I doubt it will be easy to identify what exactly it is you are after.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, so what if it contains tons of crap? As long as there are good answers people will keep finding it when searching and focus on the high voted or accepted answers.

The main use of SO (in my opinion) is for newbies who need something - they don't need diamonds, simple decorative glass gems will be good enough for them.

All of this aside, if you, as expert programmer, want to create "Hall of Fame" for questions and answers, this looks like valid feature request IMO..  so "Add to Hall of Fame" button for high rep members seems like good idea to me.. that HoF can be "system tag" to make things simple.

Of course, same way that questions can be added to the Hall members should have the ability to remove questions from there - we're all humans after all and mistakes happen. :)

Comment: I was trying to find some answers, just to find a link for use with  close as exact duplicate button. It's hard to find a question with good answers. That's what wrong with tons of crap

Comment: As for the newbies, I think SO doing evil job buy spreading recipes, not knowledge.

Comment: OK good point - you can add good questions or questions with good answers to your Favorites then, and if HoF will come to life add these questions to it. :)

Comment: @Col regarding newbies, I disagree - sometimes the simple answers are the best. When you want to bake a bread, simple recipe will make tasty bread.. if you want something more fancy you can ask. Another example.. when someone ask "How much is 1+1" he would expect plain answer "2" not answers like "depends on which base" etc. What I'm trying to say is that Q&A site is expected to give direct answers, or "recipes" as you call it.

Comment: Sometimes! Sometimes - yes! BUT NOT ALL THE TIME CONSTANT REPETITIVE MECHANICAL CHANTING OF SEVERAL STUPID MANTRAS, like that stupid bobby-tables comic. In fact, there are NO answers other than those "simple" ones on SO. and those few real helpful ones are buried under tons of simple" crap. That's exactly the point I am talking about of

Comment: @Col, *Hesitates to flag as 'insulting Bobby tables'* :)

Answer (score 1):

I like the concept of a super vote.  However, it also could be quite dangerous as +10 to a bad question could be bad...  So here's some thoughts around that:

- Perhaps +10 is too much, What about +5?  It's still a good boost, but it's more reasonable to the community as a whole.
- I would absolutely make this available for answers as well.  Too often the correct answer isn't upvoted nearly as much as the popular one.  But having the ability to supervote a good answer over top of a incorrect (or incomplete) on is huge.
- We might want to require a tag badge to enable the *supervote* button.  Which badge is up for debate as I can see justification for requiring a bronze or a gold.  But the reason is that having a tag badge proves that the voter has a prerequisite level of knowledge about the subject so should be able to know that the post is really that good.
- Giving the posting user +50 or +100 rep at one shot could make it ripe for abuse.  Perhaps the rep should instead be treated like a normal vote and they only receive +5 or +10.
- The limit should be quite low on how many times it can be used per day.  Perhaps only one or two per day would suffice.