# Dispute the closing of "What is the Ubuntu of Web Development Frameworks?" on SO

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, new-users, close-reasons

This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645739/what-is-the-ubuntu-of-web-development-frameworks-what-framework-should-i-use was closed for being "subjective and argumentative". I'd like it to be re-opened.

I'll admit that I did respond heatedly to some of the answers. I think that's justified because the answers did not address the specifics of the question. Many of the people hadn't even used the frameworks they recommended – just "this looks cool". Not the specialist knowledge I was seeking on Stack Overflow.

As to being subjective: it is. *But* isn't Stack Overflow the right place for a complete noob to find out what is the easiest framework to use?

In the two months since I asked the question, I've tried some of the frameworks people suggested and reported my progress in comments.

The best reason for opening the question is that **Stack Overflow should be accepting and helpful to noobs, not dismissive**. "What is the easiest framework" is a question that many noobs have, and while there is not an objectively correct answer, informed discussion about it could help a lot of people who want to learn to program, to create something usable and functional.

*edit: I realise that it's no one's job but my own to help me. However as I understand Stack Overflow the payoff for helping less experienced programmers is – like contributing to an open-source project – doors open to more appealing jobs (some positions expect that you have a certain Stack Overflow score for instance). Given then that SO exists to help less experienced programmers and that benefits flow both ways, why isn't commentary on choice-of-framework considered constructive? Getting started is the hardest part for a beginner.*

*Even if the answers are partly subjective, there are objective aspects to the question and knowing about objectively wrong answers is helpful even if objectively right answers are impossible.*

Comment: "*there is not an objectively correct answer*" yep, precisely.

Comment: This is a boring question. We have heaps of duplicates. And it's too broad because you even left the language open, and since you only wanted a comparison between three popular ones, you should simply check them out yourself. -- However I'm completely at loss why it was deleted now. There are *SIGNIFICANTLY worse* duplicates on SO.

Comment: @mario: it's deleted now because it was closed two months ago and presumably Mr. Tzu has gotten whatever value there was to be had. As we've noted in the answers, this isn't an appropriate question for SO, and thus it's best if we just lay it to rest.

Comment: @Mark Elliot. There are objectively *incorrect* answers and there can be fruitful discussion of my question.

Comment: @mario "Simply check them out yourself". That takes months, and would take even longer to be thorough. It's not simple like a Google search is simple. Hence a discussion on Stack Overflow could help people out.

Comment: @mario "This is a boring question." Not for newbies!

Comment: Wow, so many downvotes &ndash; and instead of my request being debated, the original Q has been deleted. How do you senior people think this comes off? I feel like you are being belittling, dictatorial, and prejudiced against the people who need the most help: beginners.

Comment: @LaoTzu: I'll say it again: There are duplicates - Use the site search. It's unclear what kind or level of thorough review you expect from SO. Maybe it would help to know what you want if **you** provided an example framework assessment first - maybe a bit more than `Tried Zend and hated it.` But regardless of that: the easy to learn factor is easy to assess by peeking into one tutorial per framework. (As it so happens, I should know; made a superficial framework overview http://matrix.include-once.org/framework/).

Comment: @mario I think the question was pretty clear. I made several edits to the level of verbosity as the answers came in. When I search for `what framework should i use` what I see is high-level and complicated.

Comment: Please list five questions from http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=simple+php+framework that you deem unsatisfactory and provide an example of what kind of answer you demand.

Comment: @mario I'm not demanding anything. I didn't know to search for `simple php framework` but several of those look good. I could list 5 unsatisfactory ones but that would just be pugnacious.

Comment: @mario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526040/simple-php-framework has good answers but it really does seem like people here find beginners anathema.

Comment: @mario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526040/simple-php-framework Most answers don't explain why a particular option is good or what's good about it. So these answers would have been just as unhelpful as the ones I received.

Comment: I'm not sure a two-liner warrants grateful answers. Boring topic that has been covered ad nauseum. And if you broadly ask for easy to learn, people won't have any specifica to comment on, but just list those that they easily picked up.

Comment: @mario Perhaps the solution is to pin up a permanent thread and make the responses really great. The search you suggested didn't come up when I typed in my question and no-one pointed me there; I would certainly have been better served by the search you suggested than by the question I asked.

Comment: @mario I didn't broadly ask for "easy to learn"; I was very specific about my skill set and exactly what I meant by easy to learn.

Comment: Yes, your title creativity has prevented any of the duplicates to come up as suggestion. It might be sensible to merge the heap of duplicates that exist. This would provide such a compendium/overview, even though most of these questions are popularity contests. But merging everything together will make it even less likely to be found by the search function. || The problem with the closevoting on your question was also that it was declared subjective. It is that too, but it's foremost a duplicate, yet nobody linked one.

Comment: @mario Did not intend the title to be creative. I was trying to be specific, to make the question more answerable than "what's the best / easiest?" . || Could a mega-compendium-thread be made findable by adding a lot of tags?

Comment: (@Lao, see the FAQ [What do votes mean on Meta? Why was my well-written post downvoted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work#47635))

Comment: @Lao Tzu: SO is not a place to get the *wrong* answer and debate it, it's a place to get the undebated *right* answer. If you're looking for a debate, you haven't come to the right place. I've got nothing against new users, but I do not agree with your errant understanding of what's relevant and what's not on this site.

Comment: @Arjan Thanks, that helps. @Mark Elliot Where *is* the right place for questions like mine?

Comment: Lao, see also [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) (You cannot notify multiple people, so @Mark did not get notified. But now he does since I did not have to "spoil" an @ on your name here.) Apart from that: not every question fits on one of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Mark Elliot You may not have anything against new people, but the FAQ @Arjan linked to makes it clear that the culture here is very much anti-noob. [cruel, elitist, and rude](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying) to new people, although "frivolous" discussion is welcomed by computer experts.

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for the @ tip. Since Stack Exchange has the best layout and the most informed communities about computer stuff, I think subjective questions like mine should be discussed on at least one of them. (That is the kernel of my OP.)

Comment: Given [your link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying), if with "here" in "the culture here" you're referring to **Meta** Stack Overflow: that seems a different issue to me.

Comment: @Lao: this is a common misconception. Stack Exchange is great *because* it was designed for a specific purpose. Using it for *any* purpose risks destroying what makes it work! You might also like to go bowling with the good folk at your local coffee shop... but bowling *in* the coffee shop isn't going to work out very well.

Answer (score 10):

I think closing this question was the correct decision.

In addition to being argumentative and subjective, I think its overly broad.  There are lots of languages with "easy" frameworks (ruby, php, python, etc.) and its pretty much impossible to make an objective comparison between them.

Questions of this nature are much better suited for the [Programmers StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: "What language should I learn next" and "which is better, X or Y" questions are generally off-topic on Programmers.SE. This often extends to frameworks, cause the reasoning involved in deciding that those questions are off-topic is pretty much the same. I can't see the question the OP references here, so I can't tell for sure if it'd be appropriate for P.SE or just closed. But, FYI and all that.

Comment: It may very well have been closed on P.SE as well. My point was just that P.SE tends to grant more latitude to subjective questions. A question like this has the best chance of success (if any at all) there.

Comment: @dbyrne Yeah, I just wanted to leave a note to avoid the impression that a "what framework should I use" question would be likely to live long and prosper on P.SE. Subjective questions in general are certainly welcome, as you say.

Comment: @dbyme It's not that broad. Whatever framework has the best tutorial, wins.

Comment: @Lao - Can you define "the best"?  Nope...that's why it's by definition subjective.  I think you're confusing two things, your desire that the question *would* fit the community, and the question not subjective.  The first is certainly a valid feeling, however that doesn't make the question any less subjective, or bring it any closer to having a correct answer.  What would you accept as an answer? What's "the best" and "easiest" *for you* isn't necessarily the same as anyone else, so the question may not be helpful to others either.

Comment: @Nick Craver I was not disputing the subjectivity, I was disputing the "overly broad".

Comment: @Nick Craver There wouldn't necessarily *have to* be a correct answer. Even just informing new people which tutorials do not work out of the box would be helpful.

Comment: @Lao At that point it also risks being too localized. Tutorials may be changed over time. Good ones can become bad and bad ones can become good.

Answer (score 5):

> But isn't Stack Overflow the right place for a complete noob to find out what is the easiest framework to use?

Um, no...

For that to be true, we'd have to assume two things about our "complete noob":

1. He has enough knowledge of web development to get past the "easy to learn == easy to use" trap (failing this, "easy" will always be synonymous with "closest to the final application he wishes to write").
2. He has enough background knowledge to read and understand answers from users with a wide range of backgrounds, and work out how they related to his own.

...aaaand we'd have to assume that the users *answering* the question wouldn't just push their favorite frameworks.

These are bad assumptions. It's pretty much the *definition* of Subjective And Argumentative.

[As dbyrne notes,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83199/dispute-the-closing-of-what-is-the-ubuntu-of-web-development-frameworks-on-so/83200#83200) you could *probably* get away with asking something like this on [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) - they're usually a bit more tolerant of the subjective stuff. But *even then*, you'd do well to head off the more argumentative aspect, and clearly define what you mean by "easy": your description of Ubuntu is probably a place to start "lots of users, lots of support, lots of documentation".

Comment: "Easy to learn == easy to use" is not a trap, it was the soul of the question. Easy to learn was all I wanted.

Comment: As @Anna Lear notes, you couldn't put it in Programmers.SE. This is such a crucial question for new people. Stack Overflow is likely to come up on top and a helpful discussion *can* be had, and then tagged so it comes up in "relevant questions" when a newbie types in their question.

Comment: @Lao: if it isn't appropriate for P.SE, then it *certainly* isn't appropriate for SO! Stack Overflow isn't meant to host discussions... Please see: [Where can I find interesting programming discussions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions)

Answer (score 2):

"Chacun á son gout." Frameworks are an issue of taste. Thus, 'what's the best framework' is inevitably subjective and frequently argumentative. Further, your question starts off on a religious-war footing by stating your subjective and argumentative view of Ubuntu in the subject.

Comment: Surely bringing up the Ubuntu comparison makes the question easier to answer! You burn a CD, push a button, and Ubuntu "just works". It's not my favourite distro but it's what I would start a newbie off with. Similarly I was looking for a framework that's the easiest to start with.

Comment: "An issue of taste" Newbies have no taste.