# OK to ask for similar Q&A or forum site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

Sometimes a question of mine gets closed or voted to be closed for reasons like it's time sensitive, too subjective, list question.. I am still looking for an answer though.
Is it OK to ask for recommendations for other similar Q&A or forum sites or is it going to be closed?

I can Google but then I have to visit all those sites which is time consuming. My guess is that some users who are active on an SE site might be active or at least know of other high quality Q&A or forum site.

Comment: Where are you thinking of asking this feeler?

Comment: @random I don't understand your question?

Comment: so are you asking if it ok to ask a question about where to post off topic questions?

Comment: @jzd I want to ask for recommendations for other Q&A sites. Ask it on a SE site.

Comment: Possible duplicate for your future question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that it will probably be closed, but maybe I'm just not mentally framing the question correctly.  For example, the question:

> What other Programming Q&A sites are there where I can ask more subjective questions than here on Stack Overflow?

does not fit the guidelines of the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) on Stack Overflow.

However, that is a somewhat meta question, so it might be fine to ask it here on Meta.

Comment: I was just typing the same thing.  This is definitely not an on-topic question for an normal SE site.

Comment: @jzd: Yeah, I don't normally like to speak for all SE sites, but in this case I think that's true.  Asking for "other similar Q&A or forum sites" once per meta seems like it should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Asking about Q&A or forum sites is not part of the topic of most Stack Exchange sites. Some sites, however, do accept reference request questions — typically what to read to understand topic X. Asking about where to research certain kinds of issues might be ok on those sites.

Some sites have one question on their Meta gathering answers to “Where can I ask questions that aren't _____ questions?”:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions
- [Where can I ask questions that aren't Super User questions?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions)
- [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions)
- [Where can I ask questions that aren't Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-science-fiction-fantasy-stack-exchange-qu)

So look amongst those questions to see if one of the answers addresses the kind of off-topic questions you'd like to find a place for. And contribute your proposals if you have some.

(And if you're active on a site that doesn't have a meta question like this, I encourage you to start one.)