# Where do Stack Overflow members go for looser discussions?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Where can I find interesting programming discussions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions)

It seems Stack Overflow is quite strict, for example, questions can't be discussions. I assume the chat rooms are equally strict.

So where do people in Stack Overflow congregate? I refuse to believe there's no provision for random discussions!

#### Related: [Where can I find interesting programming discussions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions)

Comment: You sure about that title edit, Bill? ♪

Comment: @Grace: It was a toss up, but I do think it makes a *little* bit more sense this way.  :)

Comment: @Bill okay but now where do I go for **loser** discussions??

Comment: @Daniel: You're already there. ;)

Comment: @Daniel: [Too easy.](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080331170418AAhm4TU)

Comment: @Bill: *sigh.* The amount of suck on that website is just incomprehensible.

Comment: This seems like a reprise of [this infamous question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92200/where-to-post-questions-asking-for-expert-opinion).

Comment: Thank you to those who decided not to insult me

Answer (score 20):

The chat rooms are exactly the place to go for discussions.  We are still pretty strict about profanity and abusive language in the chat rooms, but that's about it.  Subjective discussions are quite welcome.

Comment: Chat on SF actively discourages on topic discussion, boobs on the otherhand ...

Comment: @Iain, I don't know that your statement is entirely true. We have had many good on-topic subjective discussions. What we really don't like is the hold-your-hand, walk me through a two-hour long setup type 'questions'.

Comment: Yeah the SF chat 'vibe' is that its a place to relax and talk about work / the questions rather than a place to *do* work / the questions.