# On which site would it be most appropriate to ask "soft" questions regarding ergonomic computer use in industry?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have seen ergonomics-related questions on the User Experience, The Workplace, Personal Productivity, Stack Overflow, Health, and other sites in the SE network, and it seems to me relatively justifiable in each case.

I have a question regarding specific industry-standard ergonomic practices and the prevalence thereof. In which site in the network would this be most appropriate?

Comment: Sounds like a Lifehacks slot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to post questions asking for expert opinion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92200/where-to-post-questions-asking-for-expert-opinion)

Comment: @gnat that's... not even close to the same question (?). Asking a question here about "which community to post in?" is very different than "how to have a specific person on Stack Overflow answer my question." None of the answers there are useful in answering this question...

Comment: I agree with @enderland here; the questions are absolutely not related to one another in any way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Industry-standard?

I don't think any of those really are going to be good fits. Perhaps you could clarify more, but your question sounds like "I want research on what industry standards are on ergonomics and a survey of all companies."

This sort of question isn't really a good fit *anywhere* on Stack Exchange, perhaps you could clarify what you are really looking for?