# Where can I ask about how to deal with Magento hacking and security?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope, security

Recently my client's Magento store was hacked and I want to know more information about this Magento hacking.

So where should I ask questions about Magento hacking, [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to post questions asking for expert opinion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92200/where-to-post-questions-asking-for-expert-opinion)

Comment: No, it's not duplicate. I am confused between where can I ask my question.Because this question is about security and it's also about Magento technology

Comment: Security Stack Exchange has a canonical question about [dealing with a compromised server](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server).

Comment: I agree, not a duplicate. It's a pretty specific site-recommendation question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the details of your question. And sometimes, a question is applicable to more than one Stack Exchange site - in which case you should just choose one and post there. (Don't cross-post it please! Just pick one SE site).

I'm not active on Magento Stack Ecxhange, but I can give you a partial answer with respect to Information Security Stack Exchange.

If the question is "what should I do after being hacked", or "how do I harden my server", then Information Security has canonical questions for these.
You'll want to check these canonical questions first, to make sure your question won't be closed as a duplicate of them. And they contain some good advice that you'll want to apply.

[Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) is the canonical question for dealing with a compromised server.
Hardening your system is a bit more varied, it depends on what OS, database, web server etc you have. You'll want to check their [hardening tag](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=hardening) and find the canonical questions that apply to your case. There doesn't seem to be one for Magento, but there are a few about PHP, which may be the next best thing.

If your client was the target of a specific exploit, and you want to know more, then try to find out which exploit it was. See if you can find it in the online vulnerability databases.
*Don't* just ask "I found this file after a system compromise, what does it do?" Those questions quickly get closed as a duplicate of the canonical questions.
However, if you can find the specific vulnerability exploited, and you still have a question after consulting the existing online vulnerability databases - by all means ask on Information Security Stack Exchange! A question about a specific vulnerability is definitely on-topic there.

Comment: Thanks, SL Barth

one more question I have it's off topic for meta but I can see you have knowledge about security so I am asking you. what is entry door for the hacker to do something to our system ?

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara There can be a great many ways for a hacker to enter your system. I'd have to know your system to assess its vulnerabilities - and there are others who can probaly do that a lot better than I can. The posts I linked should give you a good start for securing your system. After that, you could also hire a "penetration tester" - a security professional who will try to break into your system, to see where it is vulnerable. Good penetration testers cost money, though - they are highly skilled professionals and much in demand.

Comment: Also - there is the "Top 10 web vulnerabilities" published by [owasp.org](https://owasp.org).