# Where should I post the question related to reviewing a document that I prepared for security hardening of wordpress

Tags: discussion, review, documentation

I am preparing technical documents which contain steps that can be taken to harden the security aspects of websites built using Open Source PHP frameworks. Below are some of the documents or questions that I am preparing,

1. What are steps to do for Security hardening WordPress websites
2. What are steps to do for Security hardening Drupal websites
3. What are steps to do for Security hardening Magento websites
4. What are steps to do for Security hardening Prestashop websites
5. What are steps to do for Security hardening Laravel websites

I would like to post the document on a Stack Exchange website for review & feedback. I would like to know on which one of the Stack exchaNge website i should post my questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to post questions asking for expert opinion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92200/where-to-post-questions-asking-for-expert-opinion)

Comment: Opinions are off-topic on *every* SE site. Sorry.

Comment: I do not believe the proposed duplicate sufficiently answers this user's question, particularly the pointer towards IS chat specifically. The post that the proposed dupe is closed as a dupe of wanders even further from the subject. If this question had been closed prior to S.L. Barth having a chance to answer, the OP would have still been lost about which site's chat room to check out.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there is no such site on Stack Exchange. Reviewing documents is off-topic on almost every Stack Exchange site.

The closest thing would be [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com), but a question asking them to review any one of your documents will get closed as Primarily Opinion Based.

However, if you have specific issues in your documents, you could ask them.

Also, if you have 20 or more reputation points on Information Security, you could raise the issue in their chatroom and ask if someone there was willing to have a look at your documents. You *might* just get lucky.

Also, Information Security has a number of canonical questions about hardening servers, that you may find useful as further source material for your documents. Comparing your documents to these canonical questions might help you find points that need improvement.

Comment: I suggest change 20 points to reputation.