# Best place to ask a good subjective question

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, asking-questions, subjective

I recently posted https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113374/best-places-to-work-as-a-software-engineer-for-a-new-graduate to Programmers. I didn't post it to Stack Overflow (even though that's where I know it would get viewed by the people I most want to answer it) because it's subjective. So I posted it to Programmers thinking that career advice related to software engineering would qualify, but they closed it down.

Am I not posting it in the right place? Is there somewhere better? I would give away a large portion of my reputation points on stack exchange for some good answers. It's a really important question to me, and I'd like to know the best place to ask it.

Comment: The problem is not mainly that it's subjective, but that it's also an open-ended poll/"list of X" type question with no "right" answer. There is currently no place on the network for those. ChrisF's recommendations sound reasonable

Comment: Where is the "good" subjective question you wish to ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StackOverflow & friends [aren't the only programming sites out there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions) - there are hundreds of programming forums out there that would love to discuss such things. Stack overflow is a *Q&A* site - subjective questions don't have an *"A"*.

Comment: Is that true of the entire Stack Exchange?  The forum that I posted the question on originally was Programmers.

Comment: @helixed You could try asking in one of the site's chat rooms. Subjective questions and discussion should be allowed there.

Comment: @helixed Yes, it's true for the entire Stack Exchange. Programmers != Subjective Questions nor does any other SE site.

Comment: StackOverflow & friends aren't the only programming sites out there, but most certainly those with the biggest collective intelligence.