# Where would I ask about the benefits of creating my own RPM package vs. a manual procedure?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I've researched my technical programmer/sys admin [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/697039/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-an-rpm-spec-file-as-opposed-to-manually-installin).  I got a downvote and no real answer.

Which Stack Exchange website would be the best for such a question?

Comment: Sounds like a questions that is primarily opinion based and those don't fit well in the SE model. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions)

Comment: Your SF question has a few problems.  The only question you ask in the body does not match your title.  In the body, you are asking for book recommendations and [SF's help center on-topic guidance](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) says they don't do that.  Assuming the title is your actual question, you should expand on that in the body.  And I'm not a member of SF, but "what are the benefit of" type questions are not accepted on many Stack Exchange sites as they usually do not lead to good Questions and Answers.  I'd venture a guess that your exact question isn't on-topic anywhere.

Comment: You should take a look at [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/), [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).  After reading you may find a better way to ask your actual question that could make it fit with the SE model.

Answer (score 3):

First, I invite you to read the [Stack Exchange tour page](https://serverfault.com/tour), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask). The tour and the avoid-asking page are identical on all Stack Exchange sites; the ask-about page contains both generic information and information about what is on-topic on that particular site.

You actually asked two questions.

“What are the benefits of using an RPM spec file as opposed to manually installing code?” is not suitable for Stack Exchange as is, because it's a discussion topic, not a question that potentially has a definitive answer. If you change it to ask for practical advice for your situation, it could be ok for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or both. Is the program one whose source code you maintain, or one that you must compile from source and upgrade regularly, etc.? How many machines are you deploying it to, and how often? This is the kind of information that is necessary to give a meaningful answer. SF would focus on the professional aspects of managing multiple machines; U&L would focus on RPM and related tools.

“Is there a good book …?” is not a suitable question for Stack Exchange. Use a web search engine or a book review site.