# Can't people here be nicer?

Tags: discussion, behavior, communication

I've been using this site since about two years ago, and I've realised that people are very unfriendly here. Until now, I haven't got an upvote from anyone or a positive comment on my questions, answers, or comments.

But I have to post questions because I still have many questions at my job which I can't solve by myself. I know that some questions might be stupid or silly for experts like you, but is it really necessary to be so sarcastic or unfriendly to us?

Apart from this, people always say that my questions are a kind of duplicate and have been asked by others before. I always do research and search for information before I ask a question because I don't like to waste other people's time. Sometimes I've found some posts which bore resemblance to what I'm asking, but it's still not exactly what I'm asking for. It is similar, but sometimes a slight difference can make the task more difficult.

Actually, I know that making this post will land me in getting many downvotes and someone saying something like "It's your own problem".

Can't we just make this site a bit friendlier, please???

Comment: Rude/abusive and unfriendly comments alike are not allowed here. Every comment has a flag button on the left, below the upvote button.

Comment: "*I haven't got an upvote from anyone or a positive comment to my questions, answers, or comments.*" this is a Q&A website which serves as a repository of knowledge. It is not a chat or a social network. Content is rated by its usefulness, not in order to make people feel good. Comments are similarly related to the content.

Comment: @VLAZ Of course people rate contents is not in order to make him/her feel good, but is it really necessary to be such impolite and unfriendly?

Comment: Please be specific; "make it more friendly" isn't really actionable, that's similar to "my code doesn't work" without debugging info. Rudeness/etc is already not allowed here and we have systems in place to deal with that. We can't prevent someone from being ugly in the comments, we can however clean it up, and in the event the user does it repeatedly, they can lose their ability to participate entirely.

Comment: @KevinB "make it more friendly" means "less sarcastic and rude comments". Sometimes rudeness is implicit only the people who is said to can truly understand.

Comment: unfortunately we can't prevent all sarcastic and rude comments, we can only handle them. We can't know whether or not someone is posting a rude/sarcastic comment until it has occurred, the system needs to be informed via a flag to be able to do something about it.

Comment: Flag each rude comment you find: https://i.imgur.com/MROTP5a.png

Comment: *I haven't got an upvote from anyone or a positive comment to my questions, answers, or comments.* really? I see [two upvotes and only one downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16437736/eden0516?tab=reputation) ...

Comment: Downvotes are not rude, impolite, or unfriendly. Same as how upvotes are not nice, or polite, or friendly. Voting is neutral and relates to content. You've posted a vague topic vaguely admonishing some behaviour not very specific behaviour also asking for improvement in a non-very specific manner. As Kevin says "make it nicer" is not actionable. If the problem is with comments - there is no way to interpret comment meaning before they are posted. We can only react to them with flags. If it's about voting, then there is nothing that can be done, as voting is neutral. Or is it something else?

Comment: @user1271772 the dupes aren't meant to signal *this isn't asked in good faith*. The dupes are meant to guide the OP to more context so they can rephrase their question to something actionable or answerable. That is already pretty nice of me. Not sure if I can top that later.

Comment: Voting isn't rude, closing something as a duplicate is not taking someone's concern unseriously, and wanting to write another answer to something that is a duplicate is not a reason to reopen something. Plenty of users here have already taken this post seriously, reading it to find the appropriate duplicates and falsehoods, and commenting on those. It's probably not going to end well to have different standards for any post that  calls any kind of moderation unfriendly. Especially not ones that are dishonest about never having had upvotes.

Comment: [A list of alternative sites on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409384/why-are-opinion-based-questions-banned/409391#409391). [A longer, but less credible list](https://www.quora.com/What-are-other-question-asking-websites-like-Quora). [An older list here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/). None of them are necessarily fit for this particular case, but it can not be ruled out either.

Comment: @Eden0516 A rollback-war with a mod? Really?

Comment: @KevinB Flagging the comment is too late, the damage to the user has already been made.

Comment: @Eden0516 that’s literally an impossible obstacle to overcome. If you have any real ideas that would be able to solve that at the scale of SO I’m sure many here would like to hear it.

Answer (score 26):

We're being kind to you by telling you that your questions have some kind of problem with them when you post them.  What that problem is *specifically* I don't know since you haven't provided any examples, but...

> But I have to post questions because I still have many questions at my job which I can't solve by myself.

...if you're asking questions that are about your day-to-day job on Stack Overflow, and they *read* like you're asking us to do your job for you, then that's usually where the downvotes come into play.  From our perspective, *that* much privilege to post a question related to exactly what you're working on and you expect us to turn it around for you same-day without pay is rude to *us*.

Being downvoted isn't a show of impoliteness or meanness.  It's the only mechanism we should be using to tell you whether or not your question (or answer) is good.  If you're disappointed about how that comes out, you should immerse yourself in some reading on how to improve your questions instead.

We've kind of had enough of people calling us "rude" around here.

Comment: firstly, I'm not saying that downvoting is impolite or rude, what I mean is there are many sarcasstic and mean comments. Secondly, of course I'm not like asking them to do my job, it's just because when I encounter some problems in my job, I have to ask others to deal with it.

Comment: Sarcastic and mean comments don't warrant a whole Meta post about them...you can just flag those.  Usually when someone comes to Meta to talk about something being impolite, 100 times out of 100 it's been the case that someone's felt that the moderation has been "over the top" in their assessment.  So, you're a bit of a unicorn in that vein @Eden0516.

Comment: "you should immerse yourself in some reading on how to improve your questions instead.", how? You guys don't even give me chance!

Comment: Uh...I'm not entirely sure I follow you here @Eden0516.  I get that the feedback-to-action workflow is pretty inverted; ideally you'd have read on how to write good questions beforehand but you wouldn't know what to read before you get the feedback, but ultimately...after you receive the information about your question not being the best, *then* that is the time to read up.