# Is there a Stack Exchange domain for "design" overview?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for a place to discuss design, which would boil down to pseudo-code and ideas, not code implementation.

Would https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ be a place for that?

Comment: None of the sites really allow to discuss things. If you can formulate a specific / narrow question, for example something like *Do I have all singe point of failures addressed* or *Is scaling out easier with this design, if I use a queue* you might have a post that could fit on Software Engineering but go over their [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), meta and similar questions first to make 100% sure your question would fit there. They are more strict on topicality then Stack Overflow. Ask on their meta first when you have your tuned Q ready.

Comment: Software Engineering might be what I was looking for, ty.

Comment: [A list of alternative sites on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409391). [A longer, but less credible list](https://www.quora.com/What-are-other-question-asking-websites-like-Quora). [An older list here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13198/).