# Are there any tricks to "bypass" duplicated question checking when asking on Stack OverFlow?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

I've just started learning IT and ask questions on SO a lot.

But I'm so tired of my questions being closed all the time due to duplicated reasons. They pointed me to some other question that was said to be "duplicate", and actually before asking I spent a few hours going through those questions but I didn't understand (because I am new to IT), so I just asked a new simple question.

This duplicated question system is ..... It goes like this, a 12th grader starts learning about [general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) and asking a simple question. Instead of answering the boy's question, and the teacher just gave him a 1000-page research paper written by 3 leading professors and told him that the answer lies in this research paper. Yes, the answer is in that paper, but how can he find it at 10th grade level?

Ok I thought it was a bot who close my topic. Turn out it's people who close my question. Sorry for losing temper. Still I think this place is more for professional and enthusiast than for newbie. Since for the newbie like me my question is very "naive", and sometimes I don't even understand the answer too.

The best way I can do is edit the question, clarify my problem about duplicating and hope for the best like in this answer  [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not –](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)
pppery

Comment: I deleted duplicated one since it's closed. I've just ask a new one recently and it' immediately closed. They pointed me to 2 questions which are not related to my question at all.  This is stupid

Comment: @QuangHoàngMinh I'd advise against calling it stupid, since many of the people who use meta stack exchange are the kind of people who close questions as duplicates, and you'd be annoying quite a few people. Of course, you're free to do whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm losing my temper. Since I'm mostly self-learning so SO is the place I depend on the most. I don't know where to ask other than SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)

Comment: Oh so it's people close it. I thought it was a bot, which automatically detect similar pattern or something like that.

Comment: ["*Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for* ***professional and enthusiast*** *programmers.*"](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (my emphasis). Where does the expectation come from that it is a place for complete beginners? [From the CEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPbbt7Dg-2U&t=2m57s)?. The tension with beginners on Stack Overflow is well known. One of the better received proposals to change it is *[Create a separate, independent advanced Stack Overflow, focusing on being a knowledge library (but still part of the network)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983)*.

Comment: For alternatives, [this list of alternative sites on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409391) could be reviewed. [A longer, but less credible list](https://www.quora.com/What-are-other-question-asking-websites-like-Quora). [An older list here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13198/).

Answer (score 9):

> This duplicated question system is stupid. It goes like this, a 12th grader starts learning about general relativity and asking a simple question. Instead of answering the boy's question, and the teacher just gave him a 1000-page research paper written by 3 leading professors and told him that the answer lies in this research paper. Yes, the answer is in that paper, but how can he find it at 10th grade level?

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of Stack Exchange here.

The goal of Stack Exchange is **to create a strong repository of knowledge.** Having the same question duplicated in multiple places is antithetical to that goal. Imagine finding multiple versions of the same question, each with different accepted and upvoted answers. How can you tell what's best or right? What if a standard changes and a new answer begins gaining a bunch of upvotes? How will all of the duplicate questions know?

In this light, your hypothetical situation doesn't make a lot of sense. Our goal here isn't to be your tutor or teacher (though the repository as a whole can supplement that process).

If you don't understand a prior question and answer, then research the foundations behind it! If you get stuck somewhere, ask specifically about what you don't understand there. This can often lead to good, novel questions for the platform.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to fix your problem:

#### If you think your question is not a duplicate, and the other question is completely different.

If you think this is the case, edit your question explaining why it isn't a duplicate, and check the "submit for review" box when you do so.

#### If you think the other question answers your question, but it is too complicated and you were looking for a simpler answer

Go to a chatroom and ask somebody to explain the parts of the question and its answers that you don't understand, if Google doesn't help you understand. (Make sure that you go to a chatroom that allows asking these kinds of questions though!)

There's no way to prevent your questions from getting closed as duplicate, and it happens to nearly everybody. However, this should help alleviate some of your frustration.